# How to grant access in VBA to an excel file

Tags: excel, vba, macos

When my macro wants to open an excel file, due to recent changes in MacOS, I am asked if I want to give access to this file. Is it possible to grant access automatically to this same file every time I run the macro ?

Comment: I found this, I hope it helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053044/vba-excel-username-grants-access
Cheers -John

Comment: Thanks John, seems quite related though I have some difficulty to understand it. Actually, I don't need a list but just need the file to be accessible to any user of the macro. Will try to work with it.

Comment: Actually this post seems more dedicated to restrict access to everybody but a group of people. My problem is more related with the automatic blocking by MacOS which needs to click on a message to give Excel the autorisation to open the file. So I need a way in VBA to click autorisation automatically.

Comment: Here's what I found - looks like maybe there is a system setting...? choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Security & Privacy, then click General.

Comment: High braX. Thanks for commenting. However I have not found anything there changing this behavior. I have not found either anything in Excel preferences.

Comment: You might want to ask this in a more Mac-oriented venue. My experience with Mac is limited, however, as I recall, this is an explicit security measure and the only possibility to access programmatically files is to locate them in the specific user's specific folder for that Office application. Otherwise, the user needs to confirm that code may access a file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the GrantAccessToMultipleFiles procedure [1]

```
Sub requestFileAccess()  

    'Declare Variables  
    Dim fileAccessGranted As Boolean  
    Dim filePermissionCandidates 

    'Create an array with file paths for the permissions that are needed.  
    filePermissionCandidates = Array("/Users//Desktop/test1.txt", "/Users//Desktop/test2.txt") 

    'Request access from user.  
    fileAccessGranted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(filePermissionCandidates) 
    'Returns true if access is granted; otherwise, false 
End Sub
```

Note that you can include a folder reference in the file array, and it will grant access to all documents in the folder.

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/office-mac/grantaccesstomultiplefiles